# Does Dark have an ending?

Tags: ending, dark

The Netflix-series Dark is perfectly set up so that the narrative can keep on changing. Without any spoilers: in the series our time-dimension has some unexpected properties.

However this does not mean that the in-universe narrative has to be a never-ending series. **This** story could still find some satisfactory ending.
My question is, is it known if the writers intend for this story - 3 seasons - to have a resolution?

Comment: related and possibly duplicate https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110283/how-was-dark-written

Comment: This question is rather obsolete now.

Answer (score 5):

Apparantly Baran Bo Odar, who created the show together with Jantje Friese has [posted](https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/1144329/Dark-season-3-release-date-will-there-be-another-series-of-Dark-Netflix-renewed-cancelled) on his Instagram in May 2019 that season 3 will be the final season. 
I don't have Instagram so i cannot check.

The third season will **not** answer all the questions, as Jantje Friese [says](https://www.indiewire.com/2019/06/dark-season-3-jantje-friese-netflix-1202154219/): "“But we’re not going to solve every riddle because sometimes it’s funnier [that way]. I’m still not sure about the percentage, but it’s probably 10 percent [of the mysteries] we are not goiong to answer just for the fun of it (...)"

Is this a definitive answer? What if Netflix pulls out a bag a cash for another season? I don't know.

Comment: Are you saying the Origin world will now continue?

Comment: I don't know, i still have to watch S3!